# setting projection on rsgislib output image and layers

Tags: python, gdal

I have some test code that is using rsgislib to segment an image.  From rsgislib's documentation I run:

```
from rsgislib.segmentation import segutils

inputImg = 'clipped_geotiff_image.tif'
outputClumps = 'clipped_jers1palsar_stack_clumps_elim_final.tif'
outputMeanImg = 'clipped_jers1palsar_stack_clumps_elim_final_mean.tif'

segutils.runShepherdSegmentation(inputImg, outputClumps, outputMeanImg, minPxls=100)
```

The outputMeanImg does not contain the coordinate system and other spatial information after trying to explicitly add it by:

```
rsgislib.imageutils.copySpatialAndProjFromImage(outputMeanImg, inputImg)
```

or

```
rsgislib.imageutils.assignProj(outputMeanImg, rsgislib.imageutils.getWKTProjFromImage(outputMeanImg), None)
```

For details, I have provided the output of gdalinfo below.  Can anyone suggest how to set the corrdinate system and other projection information or to convert the subdataset BAND1/DATA to a conventional raster file?

=====

% gdalinfo clip_jers1palsar_stack_clumps_elim_final_mean.kea

> Driver: HDF5/Hierarchical Data Format Release 5 Files:
>   clip_jers1palsar_stack_clumps_elim_final_mean.kea Size is 512, 512
>   Coordinate System is `' Metadata:   BAND1_DATA_BLOCK_SIZE=256d
>   BAND1_DATA_CLASS=IMAGE   BAND1_DATA_IMAGE_VERSION=1.2
>   BAND1_NO_DATA_VAL_NO_DATA_DEFINED=
>   BAND1_OVERVIEWS_OVERVIEW1_BLOCK_SIZE=256d
>   BAND1_OVERVIEWS_OVERVIEW1_CLASS=IMAGE
>   BAND1_OVERVIEWS_OVERVIEW1_IMAGE_VERSION=1.2
>   BAND1_OVERVIEWS_OVERVIEW2_BLOCK_SIZE=187d
>   BAND1_OVERVIEWS_OVERVIEW2_CLASS=IMAGE
>   BAND1_OVERVIEWS_OVERVIEW2_IMAGE_VERSION=1.2
>   BAND1_OVERVIEWS_OVERVIEW3_BLOCK_SIZE=93d
>   BAND1_OVERVIEWS_OVERVIEW3_CLASS=IMAGE
>   BAND1_OVERVIEWS_OVERVIEW3_IMAGE_VERSION=1.2
>   BAND1_OVERVIEWS_OVERVIEW4_BLOCK_SIZE=46d
>   BAND1_OVERVIEWS_OVERVIEW4_CLASS=IMAGE
>   BAND1_OVERVIEWS_OVERVIEW4_IMAGE_VERSION=1.2 Subdatasets:
>   SUBDATASET_1_NAME=HDF5:"clip_jers1palsar_stack_clumps_elim_final_mean.kea"://BAND1/ATT/DATA/FLOAT
>   SUBDATASET_1_DESC=[256x1] //BAND1/ATT/DATA/FLOAT (64-bit
>   floating-point)
>   SUBDATASET_2_NAME=HDF5:"clip_jers1palsar_stack_clumps_elim_final_mean.kea"://BAND1/DATA   SUBDATASET_2_DESC=[2500x1500] //BAND1/DATA (16-bit unsigned integer)
>   SUBDATASET_3_NAME=HDF5:"clip_jers1palsar_stack_clumps_elim_final_mean.kea"://BAND1/OVERVIEWS/OVERVIEW1
>   SUBDATASET_3_DESC=[625x375] //BAND1/OVERVIEWS/OVERVIEW1 (16-bit
>   unsigned integer)
>   SUBDATASET_4_NAME=HDF5:"clip_jers1palsar_stack_clumps_elim_final_mean.kea"://BAND1/OVERVIEWS/OVERVIEW2
>   SUBDATASET_4_DESC=[312x187] //BAND1/OVERVIEWS/OVERVIEW2 (16-bit
>   unsigned integer)
>   SUBDATASET_5_NAME=HDF5:"clip_jers1palsar_stack_clumps_elim_final_mean.kea"://BAND1/OVERVIEWS/OVERVIEW3
>   SUBDATASET_5_DESC=[156x93] //BAND1/OVERVIEWS/OVERVIEW3 (16-bit
>   unsigned integer)
>   SUBDATASET_6_NAME=HDF5:"clip_jers1palsar_stack_clumps_elim_final_mean.kea"://BAND1/OVERVIEWS/OVERVIEW4
>   SUBDATASET_6_DESC=[78x46] //BAND1/OVERVIEWS/OVERVIEW4 (16-bit unsigned
>   integer) Corner Coordinates: Upper Left  (    0.0,    0.0) Lower Left 
>   (    0.0,  512.0) Upper Right (  512.0,    0.0) Lower Right (  512.0, 
>   512.0) Center      (  256.0,  256.0)

Comment: I forgot to mention that opening the image with gdal and extracting the subdatasets(subdatasets = ds.GetSubDatasets()) returns None

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a partial solution, but not in rsgislib.

Using GDAL, I can open a subdataset:

```
from osgeo import gdal

# get the projection and geotransform from the original input image
ids = gdal.Open(inputImg, gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
gt = ids.GetGeoTransform()
wkt = ids.GetProjectionRef()
print gt

del ids

# now set the projection and geotransform for the specific subdatsert
infile = 'HDF5:"'+outputMeanImg+'"://BAND1/DATA'
ods = gdal.Open(infile, gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
ods.SetProjection(wkt)
ods.SetGeoTransform(gt)

del ods
```

The above code sets the projection and geotransform for the subdataset I am interested in, but please note that I am opening the output as ReadOnly.  If I set it to update, it fails, and it actually updates the selected dataset even though it is opened in read only mode.  I consider that a bug, but it appears to work by creating a new .aux.xml file.

There may be an easer/better way to do this, but this works for now.